# Best way to get results for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, view, triggers

I could really use some help with a project I'm working on for my summer internship. I need to know if there is a better/easier way. I've got 9 tables with information I need to consolidate into 1 table. The project is meant to help limiting the access based for a specific user  based on cl_no and c_no. We only want distinct c_no cl_no based on table. I started by writing the following script as a view to see all the relevant records I'll be working with.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
        `contacts_callmeet`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `contacts_callmeet`.`ccm_cl_no` AS `ccm_cl_no`,
        1 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `contacts_callmeet`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        `contacts_callmeet`
    WHERE
        ((`contacts_callmeet`.`ccm_status` = 1)
            AND (`contacts_callmeet`.`ccm_cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`contacts_callmeet`.`ccm_cl_no` <> 0))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `contacts_notes`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `contacts_notes`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        2 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `contacts_notes`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        `contacts_notes`
    WHERE
        ((`contacts_notes`.`cn_status` = 1)
            AND (`contacts_notes`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`contacts_notes`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`contacts_notes`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `d`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `d`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        3 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `d`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        `disbursements` `d`
    WHERE
        ((`d`.`disb_status` = 1)
            AND (`d`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`d`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`d`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `ea`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `e`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        4 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `e`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        (`events_attendees` `ea`
        JOIN `events` `e` ON ((`e`.`e_no` = `ea`.`e_no`)))
    WHERE
        ((`ea`.`ea_status` = 1)
            AND (`e`.`e_status` = 1)
            AND (`e`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`e`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`ea`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `gj`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `g`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        5 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `g`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        (`groups` `g`
        JOIN `groups_join` `gj` ON ((`g`.`g_no` = `gj`.`g_no`)))
    WHERE
        ((`g`.`g_status` = 1)
            AND (`g`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`g`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`gj`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `pledges`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `pledges`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        6 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `pledges`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        `pledges`
    WHERE
        ((`pledges`.`pl_status` = 1)
            AND (`pledges`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`pledges`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`pledges`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `ec`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `e`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        7 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `e`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        (`events_cohosts` `ec`
        JOIN `events` `e` ON ((`e`.`e_no` = `ec`.`e_no`)))
    WHERE
        ((`ec`.`ec_status` = 1)
            AND (`e`.`e_status` = 1)
            AND (`e`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`e`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`ec`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `cl`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `clp`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        8 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `cl`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        (`comm_list` `cl`
        JOIN `comm_list_parent` `clp` ON ((`clp`.`clp_no` = `cl`.`clp_no`)))
    WHERE
        ((`clp`.`clp_status` = 1)
            AND (ISNULL(`cl`.`coml_status`)
            OR (`cl`.`coml_status` = 1))
            AND (`clp`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`clp`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`cl`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
        `commitments`.`c_no` AS `c_no`,
        `commitments`.`cl_no` AS `cl_no`,
        9 AS `ti_no`,
        1 AS `ctc_status`,
        `commitments`.`a_no` AS `a_no`
    FROM
        `commitments`
    WHERE
        ((`commitments`.`commit_status` = 1)
            AND (`commitments`.`cl_no` IS NOT NULL)
            AND (`commitments`.`cl_no` <> 0)
            AND (`commitments`.`c_no` IS NOT NULL))
```

Then I realized the runtime is far to long (50+ secs) so I started writing triggers for each table to populate a table called contacts_table_clients(seen below). The triggers for one table can be seen below.

ctc_no, c_no, cl_no, ti_no, ctc_status, a_no

88, 6972179, 2000, 2, 1, 151

```
CREATE DEFINER=`IDPAdmin`@`%` TRIGGER `IDP1`.`contacts_notes_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `contacts_notes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE records int(10);


IF new.cl_no is not null
THEN

select count(c_no) into records from contacts_notes where cn_status = 1 and c_no = new.c_no and cl_no is not null and cl_no not in 
(select cl_no from contacts_table_clients where ctc_status = 1 and c_no = new.c_no and ti_no = 2);

END IF;

IF records > 0
 THEN 
INSERT INTO `IDP1`.`contacts_table_clients`
(`c_no`,
`cl_no`,
`ti_no`,
`a_no`)
VALUES
(new.c_no,
new.cl_no,
2,
new.a_no);
END IF; 


CREATE DEFINER=`IDPAdmin`@`%` TRIGGER `IDP1`.`contacts_notes_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `contacts_notes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE old_cl_no int(10);
DECLARE new_cl_no int(10);
DECLARE delete_c_no int(10);
DECLARE delete_cl_no int(10);
DECLARE records int(10);
DECLARE records_2 int(10);
DECLARE old_cl_no_select int(10);
DECLARE new_cl_no_select int(10);

IF new.cl_no > 0 and old.cl_no is null
 THEN 

 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_contacts_notes_2;
create temporary table tmp_contacts_notes_2
select c_no, cl_no,a_no from contacts_notes where cn_status = 1 and c_no = new.c_no and cl_no is not null and cl_no not in 
(select cl_no from contacts_table_clients where ctc_status = 1 and ti_no = 2 and c_no = new.c_no);


select count(*) into records_2 from tmp_contacts_notes_2;
 END IF;


 IF records_2 > 0
 THEN
INSERT INTO `IDP1`.`contacts_table_clients`
(`c_no`,
`cl_no`,
`ti_no`,
`a_no`)
VALUES
(new.c_no,
new.cl_no,
2,
new.a_no);
END IF;


IF new.cn_status = 0 or new.cl_no is null


THEN
select distinct c_no into delete_c_no
from contacts_table_clients 
where ctc_status = 1
                and ti_no = 2
and c_no = new.c_no 
and cl_no not in (select cl_no 
from contacts_notes 
                                    where c_no = new.c_no 
                                    and cn_status = 1
                                    and cl_no is not null);

select distinct cl_no into delete_cl_no
from contacts_table_clients 
where ctc_status = 1
                and ti_no = 2
and c_no = new.c_no 
and cl_no not in (select cl_no 
from contacts_notes 
                                    where c_no = new.c_no 
                                    and cn_status = 1
                                    and cl_no is not null);

    UPDATE contacts_table_clients 
    set ctc_status = 0 
    where ti_no = 2 
    and c_no = delete_c_no 
    and cl_no = delete_cl_no;

END IF;


IF new.cl_no <> old.cl_no and new.cl_no is not null and new.cl_no <> 0
THEN


select cl_no into old_cl_no
from contacts_table_clients 
where ti_no = 2 
        and ctc_status = 1
        and c_no = new.c_no
        and cl_no not in (select cl_no 
from contacts_notes 
                            where c_no = new.c_no 
                            and cn_status = 1 
                            and cl_no is not null);





select cl_no into new_cl_no
from contacts_notes 
where c_no = new.c_no 
and cn_status = 1 
and cl_no not in (select cl_no 
from contacts_table_clients 
                        where ti_no = 2 
and c_no = new.c_no
and ctc_status = 1
                            and cl_no is not null);


END IF;

IF new_cl_no > 0 and old_cl_no > 0
THEN

UPDATE contacts_table_clients set cl_no = new_cl_no where ctc_status = 1 and ti_no = 1 and c_no = new.c_no and cl_no = old_cl_no;

END IF;


IF  new.cl_no <> old.cl_no and new.cl_no is not null and new.cl_no <> 0


THEN

select distinct cl_no into delete_cl_no
from contacts_table_clients 
where ctc_status = 1
                and ti_no = 2
and c_no = new.c_no 
and cl_no not in (select cl_no 
from contacts_notes 
                                    where c_no = new.c_no 
                                    and cn_status = 1
                                    and cl_no is not null);

    UPDATE contacts_table_clients 
    set ctc_status = 0 
    where ti_no = 2 
    and c_no = new.c_no 
    and cl_no = delete_cl_no;

END IF;

















IF delete_cl_no < 0 and (old_cl_no is null or new_cl_no is null or new_cl_no < 1 or old_cl_no < 1)
THEN
INSERT INTO `IDP1`.`contacts_table_clients`
(`c_no`,
`cl_no`,
`ti_no`,
`a_no`)
VALUES
(new.c_no,
new.cl_no,
2,
new.a_no);

END IF;


IF new.cl_no <> old.cl_no and old_cl_no > 0 and new.cl_no is not null
THEN
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_contacts_notes;
create temporary table tmp_contacts_notes
select c_no, cl_no,a_no from contacts_notes where cn_status = 1 and c_no = new.c_no and cl_no is not null and cl_no not in 
(select cl_no from contacts_table_clients where ctc_status = 1 and ti_no = 2 and c_no = new.c_no);


select count(*) into records from tmp_contacts_notes;

END IF;

IF records > 0
 THEN 
INSERT INTO `IDP1`.`contacts_table_clients`
(`c_no`,
`cl_no`,
`ti_no`,
`a_no`
)
VALUES
(new.c_no,
new.cl_no,
2,
new.a_no);
END IF;





IF new.cl_no <> old.cl_no and new.cl_no is not null and new.cl_no <> 0
THEN
select count(cl_no) into old_cl_no_select
from contacts_notes 
                            where c_no = new.c_no 
                            and cn_status = 1 
                            and cl_no is not null
                            and cl_no not in (select cl_no 
from contacts_table_clients 
where ti_no = 2 
        and ctc_status = 1
        and c_no = new.c_no);

END IF;

IF old_cl_no_select > 0
 THEN 
INSERT INTO `IDP1`.`contacts_table_clients`
(`c_no`,
`cl_no`,
`ti_no`,
`a_no`)
VALUES
(new.c_no,
new.cl_no,
2,
new.a_no);
END IF;



END
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Am I going about this project in the most efficient way or is there a better/easier way?

Comment: One thing I notice with your UNION query: You are using both DISTINCT and UNION. Both sort the data to get to distinct rows. Thus you have the DBMS do the same work twice. Either remove the DISTINCTs or replace UNION with UNION ALL.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner! Which one would be quicker?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are probably not going to get a simple answer here.  When you throw up a complex query, some trigger definitions, and no information about table schema, query explain information, and what you are really trying to achieve, you are not going to get a lot of useful answers.  You are in essence opening a VERY broad question that could nave pieces of answers spread across your schema, your approach to querying, etc.  No one here knows this system to be able to give you anything but very surface-level advice.

Comment: Understood, thanks @MikeBrant. I'll make sure to be more specific with my next post. I'm going to stick with the trigger approach.

Comment: @chase cabrera: I don't know. DISTINCT makes all parts unique first and UNION ALL would have nothing to do but glue these parts together then. Without DISTINCT, it would be UNION ALL that looks at *all* records and makes them unique. I don't know if one is faster than the other. Just try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The union is ok.

Start by separating the SQL statements and observe how long each one takes.

I guess one or two of them queries a pretty large table. Do an `Explain` to find out what takes so long. There are probably some indexes missing.

Add them like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts_callmeet` ADD INDEX `ccm_status` (`ccm_status`)
```

---

I had an issue lately and solved it in a similar way. It seems like MySQL handles a separate table with indexes better than using joins and/or unions.

The approach is good (I had a performance boost of about 1500x on the first query), also as Thorsten said: think about whether you want to distinct before the union. Maybe you want that, I guess the results will be faster when you do a distinct in the end.

Comment: My issue is that the query takes over 1 second to implement I need to achieve a 200ms SLA. That's why I'm populating contacts_table _client with a trigger.

Comment: I've added indexes to two of the tables and the runtime is still well over 2 seconds for the fetch.

Comment: How many rows do the tables have and how timely accurate must the data be?

Comment: The data has to be real time as it is allowing a user to view the contact (c_no) information based on the cl_no.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan for trouble shooting this problem with me! I appreciate your feedback.